# Function bijective if component functions are bijective

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I’ve tried searching online to find that if I have a mapping $f(x,y) = (f_1(x), f_2(y))$ and both component functions are bijective is $f$ neccessarily bijective also? I couldn’t find results for this...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Try to figure if $f$ is injective, I mean, supose $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$, but then
$$
(f_1(x),f_2(x))=f(x,y)=f(x',y')=(f_1(x'),f_2(x'))
$$
and by injectivity of $f_1$ and $f_2$, then $x=x'$ and $y=y'$, so $f$ is injective.

For surjectivity, in the case that the codomain of $f$ is the cartesian product of the codomains of $f_1$ and $f_2$, then you can use the same argument; as $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective, then it is $f$.